# Spinner position and sharedpreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-spinner, android-appwidget

I have an appwidget with a simple textview, which is editable as an edittextfield in a config activity, with a spinner the user can change the textsize, I need to save a spinners selection, and restore again with sharedpreferences, and i needs the appwidgetid, so the user can add multiple appwidget.

I've tried a lot of things and done researching for 2 days now, but I can not get it to work, I get force close as soon as the widget is being added.

This is what i think looks the best, but it does not work. [Spinner Selection - Save to SharedPreferences, then Retrieve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068115/spinner-selection-save-to-sharedpreferences-then-retrieve)

This is driving me crazy! any sugestions to fix this will be VERY much appreciated

Regards Jakob Harteg

Save and load prefs

```
    // Write the prefix to the SharedPreferences object for this widget
    static void saveTitlePref(Context context, int appWidgetId, String text) {

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0).edit();
        editor.putString(PREF_PREFIX_KEY + appWidgetId, text);
        spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
        editor.putInt(spinnerSelection + appWidgetId, 0);
        editor.commit();
    }

    // Read the prefix from the SharedPreferences object for this widget.
    static String loadTitlePref(Context context, int appWidgetId) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);

            String prefix = prefs.getString(PREF_PREFIX_KEY + appWidgetId, null);

        spinner.setSelection(prefs.getInt(spinnerSelection + appWidgetId, 0));

        // If there is no preference saved, get the default from a resource
        if (prefix != null) {
            return prefix;
        } else {
            return context.getString(R.string.appwidget_prefix_default);
        }
    }
```

Almost full code:

```
public class WidgetConfig extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener{

    Dialog myDialog;
    Context context;
    static EditText info;
    static Spinner spinner;
    private static final String[] paths = { "10", "12", "14", "16", "18", "20",
        "22", "24", "26", "28", "30", "32", "34", "36", "38", "40", "50", "60"};

    File path = null;
    private static final String PREFS_NAME = "com.harteg.NotesWidgetPro.Widget";
    private static final String PREF_PREFIX_KEY = "prefix_";
    private final static String FONT_SIZE_KEY="fontsize";
    static String spinnerSelection;

    int mAppWidgetId = AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID;   

    public WidgetConfig() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.widgetconfig);
        context = WidgetConfig.this;

        // back button = cancel
        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);

        info = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etwidgetconfig);

        findViewById(R.id.bwidgetconfig).setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
        findViewById(R.id.bwidgetconfig1).setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);

        // Find the widget id from the intent.
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            mAppWidgetId = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                    AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
        }

        // If they gave us an intent without the widget id, just bail.
        if (mAppWidgetId == AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID) {
            finish();
        }

        info.setText(loadTitlePref(WidgetConfig.this, mAppWidgetId));

        //------------ Text Size spinner ---------------
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.TxtSizeSP);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(WidgetConfig.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, paths);

        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        spinner.setSelection(7);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        //--------------------------------------------------

    } // onCreate finished

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context); 

        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            info.setTextSize(10.0f);
            views.setFloat(R.id.tvConfigInput, "setTextSize", 10);
            break;
        case 1:
            info.setTextSize(12.0f);
            views.setFloat(R.id.tvConfigInput, "setTextSize", 12);
            break;

        ....

        case 17:
            info.setTextSize(28.0f);
            views.setFloat(R.id.tvConfigInput, "setTextSize", 60);
           break;  
        }
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(mAppWidgetId, views);
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

    }

    View.OnClickListener mOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // When the button is clicked, save the string in our prefs and
            // return that they clicked OK.
            String titlePrefix = info.getText().toString();
            saveTitlePref(context, mAppWidgetId, titlePrefix);


            // Push widget update to surface with newly set prefix
            AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager
                    .getInstance(context);
            Widget.updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, mAppWidgetId,
                    titlePrefix);

            // Make sure we pass back the original appWidgetId
            Intent resultValue = new Intent();
            resultValue.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                    mAppWidgetId);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, resultValue);
            finish();

        }
    };

    // Write the prefix to the SharedPreferences object for this widget
    static void saveTitlePref(Context context, int appWidgetId, String text) {

        //Getting the SharedPreference object
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0).edit();

        // save the values to preferences
        editor.putString(PREF_PREFIX_KEY + appWidgetId, text);

        spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
        editor.putInt(spinnerSelection + appWidgetId, 0);


        // Saves the values
        editor.commit();
    }

    // Read the prefix from the SharedPreferences object for this widget.
    static String loadTitlePref(Context context, int appWidgetId) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        String prefix = prefs.getString(PREF_PREFIX_KEY + appWidgetId, null);

        spinner.setSelection(prefs.getInt(spinnerSelection + appWidgetId, 0));

        // If there is no preference saved, get the default from a resource
        if (prefix != null) {
            return prefix;
        } else {
            return context.getString(R.string.appwidget_prefix_default);
        }
    }

    static void deleteTitlePref(Context context, int appWidgetId) {
    }

    static void loadAllTitlePrefs(Context context,
            ArrayList<Integer> appWidgetIds, ArrayList<String> texts) {
    }

...

}
```

UPDATE:

I added log tags like this:

```
Log.v(TAG, "before save");
        spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
        editor.putInt(spinnerSelection + appWidgetId, 0);
        Log.v(TAG, "after save");

Log.v(TAG, "before load");
        spinner.setSelection(prefs.getInt(spinnerSelection + appWidgetId, 0));
        Log.v(TAG, "after load");
```

but they don't even appear in the log:

```
11-16 21:25:08.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1337): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-16 21:25:08.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1337): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.harteg.NotesWidgetPro.Widget: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-16 21:25:08.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1337):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2236)
11-16 21:25:08.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1337):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:130)
11-16 21:25:08.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1337):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1271)
11-16 21:25:08.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1337):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-16 21:25:08.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1337):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-16 21:25:08.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1337):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-16 21:25:08.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1337):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-16 21:25:08.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1337):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-16 21:25:08.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1337):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-16 21:25:08.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1337):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-16 21:25:08.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1337):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-16 21:25:08.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1337): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-16 21:25:08.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1337):     at com.harteg.NotesWidgetPro.WidgetConfig.loadTitlePref(WidgetConfig.java:267)
11-16 21:25:08.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1337):     at com.harteg.NotesWidgetPro.Widget.onUpdate(Widget.java:32)
11-16 21:25:08.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1337):     at android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider.onReceive(AppWidgetProvider.java:66)
11-16 21:25:08.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1337):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2229)
11-16 21:25:08.470: E/AndroidRuntime(1337):     ... 10 more
```

if I delete the lines for saving and loading the position the widget works perfect

UPDATE:

I've also tried with:

variable:

```
private final static String PREF_PREFIX_KEY_FONT_SIZE = "prefix_fontsize_";
```

To save:

```
editor.putInt(PREF_PREFIX_KEY_FONT_SIZE + appWidgetId, spinner.getSelectedItemPosition());
```

to load:

```
prefs.getInt(PREF_PREFIX_KEY_FONT_SIZE + appWidgetId, spinner.getSelectedItemPosition());
```

gives me the same error. 
please help

Comment: log appWidgetId while storing and reading the preference to see if there is any issue with it...

Comment: I updatet the question, thank you

Comment: @Sam are there any obvious failures in my code?

Comment: Looks like you solved it before I got your notification, from the LogCat I would've guessed that `spinner` (or less likely `context`) was null...

Comment: Hey, I thought I got it working, but now the textsize doesn't update the first time, I would appreciate if you would take a look at it, I posted new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13433211/text-size-on-appwidget-not-changing-on-first-update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working, this is what i did

I edited my spinner to this:

```
//------------ Text Size spinner ---------------
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.TxtSizeSP);


        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(WidgetConfig.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, paths);

        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Retrieve spinner position from sharedpreferences
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME + mAppWidgetId, MODE_PRIVATE);
        int spinnerValue = sharedPref.getInt("userChoiceSpinner",-1);
        if(spinnerValue != -1) 
          // set the value of the spinner 
          spinner.setSelection(spinnerValue);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

And after all my cases in the onItemSelected() method I added:

```
// save inputed spinner position to sharedpreferences
        int userChoice = spinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME + mAppWidgetId, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = sharedPref.edit();
        prefEditor.putInt("userChoiceSpinner", userChoice);
        prefEditor.commit();
```

This might also work:
http://a2zandroidtutorials.blogspot.dk/2012/07/spinner-with-previously-selected-value.html