# Android Spinner: Set selected item as default

Tags: android, spinner

I am making an android app that asks for the users to select a country via spinner.

When the user opens the app first time, user selects a country from list.

Then when app opens second time, I want the same country to be selected. I don't want user to select the country every time the app  is opened. 
How to do that?

Comment: store the position in sharedprefs and everytime the app runs just set the position from the sharedprefs

Comment: Use *Shared Preference* and check if user enters second time then set that value to spinner check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068115/spinner-selection-save-to-sharedpreferences-then-retrieve).

Comment: Read this article, best way for that is to store string from spinner somewhere, like in `SharedPreferences` and retreive that string in `onCreate` method. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5068115/spinner-selection-save-to-sharedpreferences-then-retrieve?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Thanks guys. Will check it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `SharedPreferences` to store the selection the first time that the user selects a country, and then use `SharedPreferences` again for the app to remember the selection, when the user returns a second time.

To store the selection in a SharedPrefence:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getPreferences(0).edit();
int selectedPosition = yourSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition();
editor.putInt("spinnerSelection", selectedPosition);
editor.apply();
```

To load the selection onto the spinner when reusing the app:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(0);
yourSpinner.setSelection(prefs.getInt("spinnerSelection",0));
```

Hope this solves your issue :)

Comment: This worked. But you forgot one more line of code.

`SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(0);`

Comment: Sorry for that. I edited my answer for anyone searching for an answer in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
 String citySelected
    final CharSequence[] items = {" abc ", " def ", " ghi ", " jkl ", " mno ",
            " pqr ", " stu ",
            " vwzyz "};
    List<String> lanSelected = new ArrayList<>();
    final boolean[] checkedItems = new boolean[]{false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false};
    List<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int o = 0; o < items.length; o++) {
        temp.add(items[o].toString());
    }
    final List<Integer> seletedItems = new ArrayList();

    if (citySelected.equals("") || citySelected == null) {
    } else
        lanSelected = Arrays.asList(citySelected.split(","));

    if (lanSelected.size() > 0) {
        for (int p = 0; p < lanSelected.size(); p++) {
            String x = lanSelected.get(p);
            int xpos = temp.indexOf(x);
            if (xpos != -1) {
                checkedItems[xpos] = true;
                seletedItems.add(xpos);
            }
        }
    }

    AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, android.R.style.Theme_Material_Light_Dialog_Alert);
    } else {
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    }
    // arraylist to keep the selected items
    AlertDialog dialog = builder
            .setTitle("city")
            .setMultiChoiceItems(items, checkedItems, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int indexSelected, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                        // If the user checked the item, add it to the selected items
                        seletedItems.add(indexSelected);
                    } else if (seletedItems.contains(indexSelected)) {
                        // Else, if the item is already in the array, remove it
                        seletedItems.remove(Integer.valueOf(indexSelected));
                    }
                }
            }).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    String city = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < seletedItems.size(); i++) {
                        if (i == seletedItems.size() - 1) {
                            city = city + items[Integer.parseInt(seletedItems.get(i).toString())];
                        } else {
                            city = city + items[Integer.parseInt(seletedItems.get(i).toString())] + ",";
                        }

                    }
                    btn_city_todisplay.setText(city);
                    dialog.dismiss();

                }
            }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    //  Your code when user clicked on Cancel
                }
            }).create();
    dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use spinner method to show selected item

```
    spinner.setSelection(position);
```

Here position is the last selected position

Answer (score 1):

You can use sharedPreference to store the country you have chosen, then search the map and find the position of country in your array, finally use setSelection(int position)to set the default country